# Issue with creating JWT in .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I'm using asp.net core to create a JWT and having issues with it.

I need to create the JWT like the **pseudo code** below:

```
var headers = base64URLencode(HeaderData);
var payload = base64URLencode(payloadData);
var headerwithpayload = header + "." + payload;
 
var signature = base64URLencode(RSASHA256(headerwithpayload, privateKey));
 
var encodedJWT = headerwithpayload + "." + signature;
```

To achieve this, had created a **public X509 certificate(.cer) and a private certificate(.pfx)** with a password. The algorithm used to create the JWT is RS256.

The below code was written to create the JWT and when I validated the JWT with my public certificate in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), it is showing as a **valid signature**. However when I send it to the other team who needs to process my request, I'm getting a **401 - Unauthorized error**.

```
         // Certificate & Private Key            
         string certLocation = @"E:\PrivateCert.pfx";
         string certPassword = "####";
         var colln = new X509Certificate2collection();
         colln.Import(certLocation, certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
         var certificate = colln[0];
         var privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
         var privateSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(privateKey);

        // Header, Payload & Signature
        var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = "ClientId",
            Audience = "audience",
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("sub", "subject") }),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();         
        string jwtValue = tokenHandler.CreateToken(descriptor);
```

I understand that I'm not encoding the JWT for the second time using the signature, which might be causing the issue.

How do I:

1. Create the encoded JWT?
2. Extract the private key from the private certificate as a string, so that I can create the encoded JWT exactly like in the pseudo code.

Comment: Can you share you startup.cs?Have you set `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true`,and is your `IssuerSigningKey` the same with `privateSecurityKey`?

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou, I'm using the JWT only in the controller. I'm will be sending the JWT to another external API (which has my public cert) for getting information. So, is there any changes to be done in the startup? The code in my question contains the complete code that I've used and I haven't used the ValidateIssuerSigningKey

Comment: I mean your startup.cs in your external API.In your external API,you need to set `IssuerSigningKey` the same with `privateSecurityKey`.

Comment: I can't make changes to the external API, since it belongs to another team. Also, they use Java for their development. They have the X509 public certificate that I've sent to them to read the JWT that I will be sending. So all I need to do is create a JWT similar to the pseudo code mentioned in my question above.